# Which codecs were used in transcoding of a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

During a transcoding of a video how can I figure out which codecs were used by ffmpeg to decode and transcode the video.

For eg. when I do `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi`

How can I know which codecs where used to decode the input file and encode to the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Koby Douek's answer is not applicable here.

Mediainfo and ffprobe will indicate the bitstream syntax but to answer the OP's Q:  "*How can I know which codecs where used to decode the input file and encode to the output?*", one can run

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi 2>&1 | sed -n "/Stream mapping/,/Press/p"
```

whose output will be like

```
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

This informs us that the first output stream mapped was the 2nd input stream, of type H.264 and decoded using ffmpeg's native H.264 decoder. This stream was encoded to H.264 using the libx264 encoder.

The given command actually performs the conversion, but the mapping info is displayed just before processing starts, so either abort the command or redirect the log to file by adding `-report` and parse that file for the info.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mediainfo`:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Codec%" output.avi
```

If not, use [`ffprobe`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) (comes with `ffmpeg` installation):

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name \ -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 output.avi
```